# SQL: counting and grouping values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, in one table I have just category_id and category_name and some information about categories. 
Another table has different category topics, and some topics are active and some are inactive, tables are related with category_id

My goal is to get all category list and count how many topics each category has, but I only want to count active topics.

My current query:

```
select t2.category, count(*) from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.category_id=t2.category_id
where t1.status=active
group by t2.category
```

This query gives and counts only active categories. How to get inactive categories as well? Result what I am tring to achieve is something like this:

Caltegory name: topics(counted):
category1: 1234
category2: 10
category3: 0 - means there is no active topics in this category
category4: 240

Comment: How to get inactive categories as well?..Can't we remove status =active column

Comment: use `left join` instead of `(inner) join`.

Comment: your question isn't much clear,please show some sample data and explain along with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `where` criteria and use `conditional aggregation` instead:

```
select t2.category, count(case when t1.status = 'Active' then 1 end) 
from table1 t1
    join table2 t2 on t1.category_id=t2.category_id
group by t2.category
```

---

Or if there is no data in `table1`, use an `outer join` instead:

```
select t2.category, count(t1.status) 
from table2 t2 
    left join table1 t1 on t1.category_id=t2.category_id and t1.status = 'Active'
group by t2.category
```

Answer (score 0):

If you group by both the category and the status, that should give you what you want:

```
select t2.category, t1.status, count(*) 
from table1 t1
    join table2 t2 on t1.category_id=t2.category_id
group by t2.category, t1.status
order by t2.category, t1.status
```

Results will be something like this:

```
Category   Status     Count   
Category1  Active     1
Category1  Inactive   2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use left join and check for null value (no topics)

```
select t1.category_name, ifnull(count(*),0( from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.category_id=t2.category_id
group by t2.category
```

Answer (score 0):

Say Table 2 is your category and Table 1 contains topic and status information.

You can use a left join for the desired output.

```
SELECT t2.category, Count (t1.categoryId) ActiveTopics
FROM Table2 t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1 on t2.categoryId=t1.categoryId
    AND t1.status= 'Active'
GROUP BY t2.category
```